# How to reduce stack trace when throwing error (point to call site)

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, stack-trace

I have a function like this:

```
function foo() {
  throw new Error('`foo` has been removed in favor of `bar`')
}
```

When someone calls `foo`, I want the stack trace (error output) to point at the call site of `foo`, not the `throw` line inside of `foo`.

For instance, I get this:

```
$ node test.js

/home/ubuntu/tmp/test.js:2
  throw new Error('`foo` has been removed in favor of `bar`')
        ^
Error: `foo` has been removed in favor of `bar`
    at foo (/home/ubuntu/tmp/test.js:2:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/tmp/test.js:5:1)
    ...
```

How do I get this instead?

```
$ node test.js

/home/ubuntu/tmp/test.js:5
  foo()
  ^
Error: `foo` has been removed in favor of `bar`
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/tmp/test.js:5:1)
    ...
```

Comment: If your goal is function name anonymity, this is probably the wrong approach.

Comment: But that's where you threw the error...

Comment: Note only Node does this.

Comment: Relevant: the code where Node adds these two lines to the output. https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7b9771f569238e9b92a22a027815ca08391cb367/src/node.cc#L1335-L1433

Answer (score 15):

**Step 1: Define a custom Error object.** For more information: [A String is not an Error](http://www.devthought.com/2011/12/22/a-string-is-not-an-error/).

```
function CustomError (msg) {
  Error.call(this);

  // By default, V8 limits the stack trace size to 10 frames.
  Error.stackTraceLimit = 10;

  // Customizing stack traces
  Error.prepareStackTrace = function (err, stack) {
    return stack;
  };

  Error.captureStackTrace(this, arguments.callee);

  this.message = msg;
  this.name = 'CustomError';
};

CustomError.prototype.__proto__ = Error.prototype;
```

**Step 2: Use `Domain` to catch the uncaught error.**

```
function foo() {
  throw new CustomError('`foo` has been removed in favorof `bar`');
};

var d = require('domain').create();

d.on('error', function(err) {
    /*
     * customize the output here.
     */
});

d.run(function() {
  foo();
});
```

**Step 3: Customize the output.** The structured stack trace is an Array of CallSite objects, each of which represents a stack frame. A CallSite object defines [these methods](https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi#Customizing_stack_traces).

```
  for(var index=0; index<err.stack.length; index++){
    var frame = err.stack[index];

    var unit = frame.getFunctionName() || frame.getMethodName();
    if (unit === null) {
      unit = 'function()';
    } else {
      unit += '()'
    }

    if (index === 0) {
      console.error('%s:%d:%d\n  %s\n  ^',
        frame.getFileName(),
        frame.getLineNumber(),
        frame.getColumnNumber(),
        unit);

      console.error('Error: ' + err.message);

    } else {
      console.error('    at %s (%s:%d:%d)',
        unit,
        frame.getFileName(),
        frame.getLineNumber(),
        frame.getColumnNumber());
    };
  }; // END. stack trace
```

**Run this program and we get the following output:**

```
/home/ray/dev/test/error.js:57:9
  foo()
  ^
Error: `foo` has been removed in favorof `bar`
    at function() (/home/ray/dev/test/error.js:53:3)
    at b() (domain.js:183:18)
    at Domain.run() (domain.js:123:23)
    at function() (/home/ray/dev/test/error.js:52:3)
    at Module._compile() (module.js:456:26)
    at Module._extensions..js() (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load() (module.js:356:32)
    at Module._load() (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain() (module.js:497:10)
```