# Show only my lines of code in error stack trace in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, stack-trace

Is there a way to filter out the lines of code from error stack trace that I can't control or debug? I mean, my nodeJS project depends on many third party dependencies and I don't pretend to debug them. It just ads noise to the stack trace.

For example, here I just want to show lines 1 and 7, because the file `prepareServer.js` is the one I created, all the others are not mine.

```
Error
    at buildAdministrationsObject (/home/joao/dev/geoptapi/prepareServer.js:350:11)
    at /home/joao/dev/geoptapi/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3638:28
    at replenish (/home/joao/dev/geoptapi/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:443:21)
    at iterateeCallback (/home/joao/dev/geoptapi/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:427:21)
    at /home/joao/dev/geoptapi/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:324:20
    at /home/joao/dev/geoptapi/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3643:17
    at /home/joao/dev/geoptapi/prepareServer.js:158:7
    at wrapper (/home/joao/dev/geoptapi/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:271:20)
    at iterateeCallback (/home/joao/dev/geoptapi/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:424:28)
    at /home/joao/dev/geoptapi/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:324:20
```

Basically I just want to show in the stack files within my project and exclude files in `node_modules/`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reduce stack trace when throwing error (point to call site)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725296/how-to-reduce-stack-trace-when-throwing-error-point-to-call-site)

Comment: @esqew no, I just want to strip out lines of code I can't control

Comment: you technically can control of these things.. but you can just leave the things that are in a directory of your choosing.. but then what if you're requiring things outside of that directory? it goes back to `you technically can control of these things` and "only my lines of code" can be different for everyone.. also im not the one minusing from u btw

Comment: @TheBombSquad technically I can control, but it is not part of the scope of a common nodejs dev project. Even Atom for example ignores files inside `node_modules/` when you do a search query within the project. In 99% of the times it just adds noise.

Comment: that's the thing.. when I see errors coming from the files.. the files are usually named in such a way that you can tell where the error happened.. if you want to know how a plane crashed, the full story is always helpful ;-;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with this solution that strips out any line with `/node_modules/` or `\node_modules\`

```js
const stripedStack = (new Error().stack).replace(/^.*[\\/]node_modules[\\/].*$/gm, '').replace(/\n+/g, '\n')
console.error(stripedStack)
```

Now as I wanted :)

```
Error
    at readShapefile (/home/joao/dev/geoptapi/prepareServer.js:106:16)
    at /home/joao/dev/geoptapi/prepareServer.js:100:7
```

Use for example like this with try/catch

```js
try {
  // some code to run
} catch (err) {
  console.error(parseErr(err))
}

function parseErr(err) {
  return ((new Error(err).stack).replace(/^.*[\\/]node_modules[\\/].*$/gm, '').replace(/\n+/g, '\n'))
}
```

Comment: what if you're requiring a package that you made

Comment: @TheBombSquad I don't care, that package should be robust and have its own test scripts passed before going into production. Even if it has an error, as I said, you're mentioning 1% of the cases. I'd say 99% of the cases you use tested third-party packages and the problem resides in _your_ code. The rest is noise. Furthermore I just want this to be _optional_. There's should be a way in NodeJS stack trace for distinguishing your code from someone else's code

Comment: How to use this? Where to put it?

Comment: @sanjarcode I edited my reply, tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Use the CLI option

1. Direct `node` - `NODE_OPTIONS='--stack-trace-limit=0' node myApp.js`
2. npm script - `NODE_OPTIONS='--stack-trace-limit=0' npm myStart`

Optional: you change the value (zero here). Negative values print less, and positive prints more. For example - setting to 10 will print only the first 10 `node_modules` errors.

Source: https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html

### Override default stack size (the actual problem)

Node limts the default error stack size (number of errors). To print all errors, run the following:

```bash
NODE_OPTIONS='--trace-warnings --stack-trace-limit=100000' node app.js
```

Optional: You can replace 100000 to set the limit.

Comment: but that just limits the number of lines for the stack trace, right?

Comment: you're right, this won't work if app code traces are between two node_module traces, will edit